# Offset UITableView Index - Overlap with iAd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, iad

I have a table based app with an iAd at the top. I have added a A-Z index to the Table View. The index is now obscured by the iAd at the top.

Can anyone suggest a good way to fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Apple Developer account there is a video from WWDC 2010 that demonstrates how to use iAd. This can be found if you go to: http://developer.apple.com/videos/ which will open iTunes. Then go to WWDC 2010 Sessions -> Application Frameworks -> Session 112 - Integrating Ads with iAds.

This will show you how to move the banner in and out of a view depending on if an ad is loaded correctly.

Comment: Doesn't address the issue of the overlapping index

Answer (score 0):

You can drag a UIView on top of a UITableView in Interface Builder to give the UITableView a header or footer view, which you can place the iAd in and have it not interfere with the tableView's contents.